# как передать JSON в ListAdapter и как нельзя делать :)

Tags: java, android, json

Здравствуйте, с сервера приходит вот это, никак иначе:

```
{
"Ключ": Значение,
"Ключ2": Значение,
"Ключ3": Значение
}
```

Я хочу засунуть и ключ и значение в `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>` цикл, например:

```
 hm = new HashMap<>();
 hm.put(NAME, "КЛЮЧ");
 hm.put(VALUE, "ЗНАЧЕНИЕ"); 
list.add(hm)
```

И потом через `SimpleAdapter` вывести в `ListView` примерно вот так:

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, CountersList,
        R.layout.list_downtime, new String[]{NAME, VALUE},
        new int[]{R.id.date, R.id.downtime});
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: что не получается?

Comment: Я хочу засунуть и ключ и значение в ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> цикл - это не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала пара принципов работы `ListView`, а именно - зачем ему нужен `List<Map<String, Object>>`.
Список `ListView` выводит на экран коллекцию элементов. Каждый элемент содержит набор каких-то данных. То есть на экране вы увидите список элементов, а в каждом элементе - свой список данных. Таким образом, один элемент представляет собой `map` "ключ - значение", где ключи отвечают за хранение данных, а **значения достаются и выводятся**. А список таких элементов, содержащих `map` с несколькими ключами и значениями, как раз и обеспечит вывод списка на экран, поэтому все наши `map`ы мы кладем в `List`.
*Таким образом, ваша задача "вывести и ключ, и значение в элемент списка" несколько нарушает принципы работы, и правильное её решение я вижу иначе (напишу в конце). Но она имеет право на существование в "учебных целях"*.

Я разбирал JSON руками, без сторонних библиотек типа GSON, Jackson и т.д.
Сделал это так:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

StringBuilder s; //строка, содержащая весь JSON
dataEntries = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>(); //список мапов для передачи адаптеру
...

JSONArray data = new JSONArray(s.toString());
for(int i=0; i<data.length(); i++) { //обходим JSONArray (коллекция)
    JSONObject dataEntry = data.getJSONObject(i); //каждый JSON-объект из коллекции
    Iterator<String> key = dataEntry.keys(); //коллекция ключей JSON-объекта
    Map<String, String> entry = new HashMap<>(); //новый map, в который положить прочитанные ключ/значение
    while(key.hasNext()){ //обходим все ключи JSON-объекта
        String nextKey = key.next();
        entry.put(nextKey, dataEntry.getString(nextKey)); //и кладем их в map
    }
dataEntries.add(entry); //добавляем map в список мапов для адаптера
}
```

В результате один элемент списка `ListView` отображает один JSON-объект: только значения всех его ключей (см. последнюю картинку). Мне не нужно было, чтобы в `ListView` вывелись **имена ключей** JSON-а. Вы же хотите получить вывод в элемент списка именно "ключ" и "значение". Поэтому в вашем случае добавление в `map` коллекции `JSONArray` будет малоосмысленным: вы не сможете отделить поля одного объекта от полей другого. Так что вы можете только один JSON-объект таким образом вывести, и у вас **весь** ListView будет отображать **всего один** JSON-объект, **каждый элемент** ListView будет соответствовать **одному полю "ключ - значение"** объекта, и содержать будет 2 строки: ключ и значение. **Внимание, собственно ответ на ваш вопрос.**

```
JSONObject dataEntry = new JSONObject(s.toString()); //строка JSON содержит только один объект
Iterator<String> key = dataEntry.keys();
while(key.hasNext()){ //обходим все ключи JSON-объекта
    String nextKey = key.next();
    entry.put("KEY", nextKey) //кладем ключ
    entry.put("VALUE", dataEntry.getString(nextKey)); //кладем значение
    dataEntries.add(entry); //добавляем в список ключ и значение
}
```

**В результате вы получите вот что:**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь пару слов о том, как я считаю корректным реализовать вывод и ключа, и значения.
Нужно создать xml-разметку одного экранного элемента `item.xml` такого вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Затем написать свой адаптер (об этом хорошо написано [здесь](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html)) и передать ему правильно сформированный `map`, как у меня в первом примере кода. А внутри этого адаптера выводить ключи в левые поля, а соответствующие им значения - в правые поля.
**Правильный результат вывода ключей и значений:** [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь, доступно объяснил, почему "неправильно хотеть того, чего вы хотите" :)

Вид списка, содержащего только значения (у вас будет *бесполезный* список, не отделяющий по смыслу имена ключей от их значений):
[image: Скрин моего лист-вью]

Comment: Спасибо большое, все понял, все получилось, к сожалению так приходят мне данные и я не могу  с этим ничего сделать....

Comment: Приходит только один объект? Тогда для его отображения не нужен ListView. Если приходит несколько объектов (не важно, за один раз или "поштучно"), то нужно делать правильно. Вопрос не в том, как приходят данные. Вопрос в том, что именно вы с ними сделаете и как выведете на экран. Так что всё вы можете сделать :) Вы программист, и должны выдать качественный продукт. Потенциального пользователя не волнуют детали реализации, вместе с тем фактом, что что-то якобы зависит не от вас.